Optimizing Python code to read multiple big matrices from a text file
I have a numerical simulation that spits out a text file with a sequence of square matrices with complex entries. They look like this:
 (#,#)   (#,#)   (#,#)
 (#,#)   (#,#)   (#,#)
 (#,#)   (#,#)   (#,#)
-----

 (#,#)   (#,#)   (#,#)
 (#,#)   (#,#)   (#,#)
 (#,#)   (#,#)   (#,#)
-----

...

I want a fast way of reading this files and store the matrices as numpy arrays in a list. I wrote the following python code to try and solve this problem
with open(f'fort.{n}', 'r') as f:
    l = [[num for num in line.split(' ') if num != ''] for line in f]

l = list(filter((l[-2]).__ne__, l))

l = [[num for num in line if num != '\n'] for line in l]
l = [[split(num) for num in line] for line in l]

l = list(filter(([['-----\n']]).__ne__, l))

l = [[float(num[0])+1j*float(num[1]) for num in line] for line in l]

Solutions = []
for i in range(len(l)):
    if (i+1)%160 == 0:
        Solutions.append(l[i-159:i+1])

but the output files contain hundreds of 160x160 matrices and my program is taking most of its running time to read them. I want to optimize this process but don't know how.

Use tag [tag:fortran] instead of [tag:fortran77] for Fortran questions and, generally, follow the tag description displayed when adding the tags. However, I do not see any reason for the [tag:fortran] tag here.

It is much more efficient to use binary data formats to exchange data between programs. Not only are they smaller, but translating between the binary and text representations requires significant CPU time.

@VladimirFГероямслава that makes sense, I'll try to change how my program generates the output files. I used the fotran77 tag because my simulation is written in it, but thanks for the heads up.

have you seen https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html?

@dankal444 this helped me a lot! I found a module that lets you write Fortran arrays as .npy files and it much better than my old solution. Thank you so much!

As @dankal444 pointed out in his comment, the .npy format is much better to do what I want, which is transfering data from a Fortran program to a Python script that analyses it. With that in mind, I found a module that lets you write Fortran arrays as .npy files. It looks to be as fast as writing the arrays in unformatted binary files.
